# Removing elements of dataframe with different number of columns

Tags: python, bash

I have a tsv file that looks like this:

```
BCM92732.1  sialidase   Abditibacteriota    bacterium
VTR99890.1  sialidase   :   Sialidase   Precursor   OS=Rhodopirellula   baltica (strain SH1)    GN=RB3353   PE=4    SV=1:   BNR_2   Tuwongella  immobilis
QEL17956.1  putative    retaining   sialidase   Limnoglobus roseus
AMV31440.1  Sialidase   precursor   Pirellula   sp. SH-Sr6A
```

I want to "clean" this file, for example, removing some columns:

```
BCM92732.1 Abditibacteriota bacterium
VTR99890.1 Tuwongella   immobilis
QEL17956.1 Limnoglobus  roseus
AMV31440.1 Pirellula    sp. SH-Sr6A
```

I thought about removing columns, however, the number of columns is different between rows.
I´m using bash for that task.
Is any better way to do that? For example, python or perl?

Comment: you only need to keep the last 2 items?

Comment: not necessarily, because some species have strain names, for example: ```Pirellula    sp. SH-Sr6A```

Comment: then what are the rules to delete column or retain column?

Comment: what do you mean by different number of columns? Tables usually do have constant number of columns

Comment: The "rules" are to keep the first column (ID) and the name of the species (with their strain if it's present)

Comment: The first step to do is to find a way to cleanup your columns in a precise way, that can be coded.  Whichever language you chose, the logic behind the cleanup is critical.  Ex. how do you define the name of the species?  How can a computer know what is included - or not - in the species?  When that is done, get started, research and ask a specific question on what is keeping you from completing the assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to the problem that provides the correct answer on the example data provided:

```
# Create a working dir
mkdir -p taxdump
cd taxdump

# Create your 'example.tsv' file
cat <<EOF > example.tsv
BCM92732.1  sialidase   Abditibacteriota    bacterium
VTR99890.1  sialidase   :   Sialidase   Precursor   OS=Rhodopirellula   baltica (strain SH1)    GN=RB3353   PE=4    SV=1:   BNR_2   Tuwongella  immobilis
QEL17956.1  putative    retaining   sialidase   Limnoglobus roseus
AMV31440.1  Sialidase   precursor   Pirellula   sp. SH-Sr6A
EOF

# Download and unpack the NCBI taxonomy database (~50mb)
curl "https://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pub/taxonomy/taxdump.tar.gz" -o taxdump.tar.gz
tar -zxvf taxdump.tar.gz

# Grab the second column (the species names) and clean up the whitespace
awk '
BEGIN{FS="|"}
$0 ~ "scientific name" {
    gsub("\t", "", $2)
    sub("^ ", "", $2)
    print $2
}' names.dmp > bacteria_names

# Use AWK to cycle through bacteria_names (i.e. every species in the db)
# and check for matches with your tsv file ("example.tsv").
# Start by looking at the last four columns of example.tsv,
# then the last three columns, then the last two columns.

awk '
NR==FNR {
    four_names[$1" "$2" "$3" "$4]
    three_names[$1" "$2" "$3]
    two_names[$1" "$2]
    next
}
{
    four_example=$(NF-3)" "$(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$NF
    three_example=$(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$NF
    two_example=$(NF-1)" "$NF
    if (four_example in four_names)
    {
        print $1, four_example
    }
    else if (three_example in three_names)
    {
        print $1, three_example
    }
    else if (two_example in two_names)
    {
        print $1, two_example
    }
}' bacteria_names example.tsv

# Results:
BCM92732.1 Abditibacteriota bacterium
VTR99890.1 Tuwongella immobilis
QEL17956.1 Limnoglobus roseus
AMV31440.1 Pirellula sp. SH-Sr6A
```